# One variable declaration creates multiple instances

Tags: c++

Here is a simple example:

```
class A {
public:
  A() {
    printf("%p C1\n", this);
  } 
  A(const char* p) {
    printf("%p C2\n", this);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  A a;
  a = "abc";
}
```

In the code, although `A` is declared just once, there are two instances of `A` getting created. The constructor gets called twice. I could reproduce this in VS 2013 as well as gnu C++.

Wondering if this behavior is a bug or part of the specifications.

Comment: You can avoid the temporary by defining an `A::operator=(const char*)` (or better `A::operator=(std::string const&)`).

Comment: `Wondering if this behavior is a bug`  You used two compilers used by  thousands of people and companies all over the world, and got the same results from such trivial code.  Given that, what chance is there of this being a bug?

Comment: @MatthewMoss My question at the end of my comment was really meant to be sarcastic.  The program is a toy program, g++ and Visual Studio are used by thousands of people.  If this was a bug, it would have been reported all over the net (add to that the probability that two independent compiler vendors would produce the same bug with such a ridiculously simple program).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have not disabled the auto-generated assignment operator or copy constructor, your class actually looks like this to the compiler:

```
class A {
public:
  A() {
    printf("%p C1\n", this);
  }
  A(const A& rhs) { }
  A(const char* p) {
    printf("%p C2\n", this);
  }
  A& operator=(const A& rhs) { return *this; }
};
```

So `a = "abc"` is interpreted as  `a.operator=( A("abc") )`

It expects a `const A&` as an argument to `operator=`, which it can construct because you provided a constructor `A(const char*)`.

You can prevent unintended conversions by making the constructor explicit.

```
class A {
public:
  A() {
    printf("%p C1\n", this);
  }
  explicit A(const char* p) {
    printf("%p C2\n", this);
  }
};
```

Then this should fail to compile:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  A a;
  a = "abc";
}
```

Unless you explicitly construct:  `a = A("abc");`

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianHackl . It is a good practice to make conversion constructors `explicit` unless you are very aware of what you're doing. And maybe not even then...

Answer (score 6):

It is part of the specification. When you do this:

```
a = "abc";
```

a temporary `A` object is created form the `"abc"` expression on the RHS using the `A(const char* p)` constructor. This is used to assign a value to `a`.

If you did this instead

```
A a = "abc";
```

you'd only see one constructor call.

Comment: For completeness, you could overload `operator=(const char *)` to take over the assignment, providing a better match than creating a temporary object.